# Appending with divs and classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok so i'm currently learning Jquery and cannot find an answer to my question. I am building a shopping list app, and it is supposed to append to the page whatever you input. It appends with the class for the box around word, but I don't know how you would go about adding in the check and delete box in the same div. Every way I try adds it outside in a seperate div or changes the properties of the one already being appended. I might not have explained it clearly enough considering this is new to me, but if you need more info, just ask. Thanks.
https://github.com/Masonwharr/shoppinglist/tree/master/Shopping-List
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0eky.png

Comment: we need to see enough code here to replicate your issue ...

Answer (score 1):

Basically, to answer your question, you have to write out all of the html code that you want to be added by jQuery when the button is clicked. You could do something like this where when you click on the "Submit" button it would call the `AddToshoppingList()` function below:

```
function AddToShoppingList(itm) {
    var li += "<li><span class='shopping-item'>" + itm.Name + "</span>";
    li += "<div class='shopping-item-controls'>";
    li += "<button class='shopping-item-toggle'><span class='button-label'>check</span></button>";
    li += "<button class='shopping-item-delete'><span class='button-label'>delete</span></button>";
    li += "</div></li>";
    $("#ShoppingList").append(li);    
}
```

and set an ID to your `<ul>` list like below, so that you can specify where you are appending the new item to:

```
<ul id="ShoppingList" class="shopping-list">
... snip ...
</ul>
```

That should get you started and you can customize the buttons to call other jquery functions when those are clicked like deleting the item.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly. You probably have to explain more in detail so we can better help you. My idea is to get the html from the page and use it when you append html to the page with js. (It should really be a template even for the ones that are already on the page...)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#js-shopping-list-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
      var inputfield = $('#entry').val();
      console.log(inputfield);
      $('.shopping-list').append('<li><span class="shopping-item">'+ inputfield + '</span>' + $('.shopping-item-controls').html() + '</li>');
      // This is incorrect, and adds an outside empty box. $('.shopping-list').append('<div class="shopping-item-controls"> <button class="shopping-item-toggle">' + '</button> </div>');
    //$('inputfield').appendTo('body').addClass('.shopping-item'); 
  });  
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

button, input[type="text"] {
  padding: 5px;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

#shopping-list-item {
  width: 250px;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.shopping-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.shopping-list > li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 20px;
}

.shopping-item {
  display: block;
  color: grey;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.shopping-item__checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Shopping List</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/4.2.0/normalize.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Shopping List</h1>

    <form id="js-shopping-list-form">
      <label for="shopping-list-entry">Add an item</label>
      <input type="text" name="shopping-list-entry" placeholder="e.g., broccoli" id="entry">
      <button type="submit">Add item</button>
    </form>

    <ul class="shopping-list">
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">apples</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">oranges</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item shopping-item__checked">milk</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span class="shopping-item">bread</span>
        <div class="shopping-item-controls">
          <button class="shopping-item-toggle">
            <span class="button-label">check</span>
          </button>
          <button class="shopping-item-delete">
            <span class="button-label">delete</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```